# Como desabilitar materialize input

Tags: html5, css3, front-end, materialize

Percebo que com o Framework materialize assim que coloco uma input ele já estiliza pelo type. Mas não quero utilizar a estilização para as input, como desabilitar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não creio que aja uma maneira de desabilitar uma property do seu arquivo.

O que eu recomendo é:

- Caso tenha importado a folha de estilo para o seu projeto, procure a tag input e remova todas estilizações;
- Cria a sua folha de estilo com suas próprias estilizações sobrescrevendo assim as do materialize.

Caso opte pela segunda, uma das maneiras de tirar essas estilizações previamente setadas no css é:

```
input {
  all: initial;
}
```

ou, dependendo do que você quer

```
input {
  all: unset;
}
```

O problema dessa solução, é que não é muito bem aceita em todos os navegadores, ainda.

Você pode encontrar mais referencias sobre o all em:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all

Comment: O ruim é que tem que ficar usando !important depois

Comment: Não amigo, não precisa não. CSS é cascata, a regra que é aplicada depois, sobrescreve a que foi aplicada antes. O !important só vai fazer com que uma regra seja aplicada independente das outras. Aproveite essa característica do CSS de sobrescrita e evite o máximo possível o uso do !importante. Abraço :)